# Are the steps involved in OOAD well-established?

Tags: uml, user-interface, ooad

There is a number of books written about OOAD (object-oriented analysis and design). A few of them can probably be considered good books, written by people with a lot of experience in the field.

One could say there is reasonable agreement on what OOAD is, to the point he/she could read a few books and not find (very) disparate elements.

So far on that subject I've read Larman (*Applying UML and Patterns: an introduction to OOAD and the iterative process*).

It begins with the functional requirements (because the non-functional ones are not the book's focus), then goes on to elaborate the use cases and then models the domain across a number of iterations. Somewhere else I've seen activity diagrams being used at an early stage but maybe they didn't fit the examples mentioned in the book. Also the user interface is not defined early (not the book's focus and is postponed to later iterations).

Can we say:

a) activity diagrams can optionally be used at the early stages of OOAD?

b) user interface is meant to be defined in later stages?

c) are the steps/activities in OOAD mostly well established?

or:

a) the steps are not well established, to the point activities cannot be reasonably defined and applied depending on the necessity.

Comment: I can say one thing definitively: "Object-Oriented Analysis and Design" is five words.

Comment: What is the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-oriented_analysis_and_design) on OOAD lacking?

Comment: @RobertHarvey Citations for verification.

Comment: @RobertHarvey I've changed the question. Hopefully it is an improvement.

Comment: I don't own that book, sorry.

Comment: @RobertHarvey I don't think owning that book is necessary. Just a general understanding/agreement on what OOAD is (or at least its valuable parts).

Comment: So here's my take.  Object-orientation is already a field of study encompassing many different subjects.  Things like inheritance, composition, polymorphism, etc.  Humans package these things up into bundles because they want to understand how they relate to each other.  Programmers are particularly prone to attempts at finding and making precise definitions for things.  You won't find those here.  Fields of study are just that: areas in which you can learn things.  Like the farmer (who also has fields), you might plant corn one day, strawberries the next.

Comment: @RobertHarvey: the OP was not asking for "object orientation" at a whole.

Comment: @Piovezan: it would be nice if you keep the question contend fixed, I was answering to the former version of your question, but the new titile invalidates my answer now to some degree. Consider to revoke your last edit.

Comment: @DocBrown: Yes, I know that.  Did I miss something?  Object Oriented Application and Development is a "process" by which OO is used to build applications in an Agile context.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Not necessarily agile, just iterative. Look. I've been programming only Java for a long time. Badly and under OCD most of the time (but don't sweat it, I'm just saying I have a few years to make up for). I just want to learn how to properly design my classes. From my limited experience and from what I've read (not only from that one book) I've come to conclusion that a somewhat formal and "proper" method of achieving that is to go through requirements, use cases (or user stories for that matter, I have yet to deepen my learning on them)...

Comment: ...and developing a domain model, among other things that are not the focus of OO analysis/design. So I study them in hopes of becoming a better programmer/designer in current and future projects. So if OOAD is not well defined, the next question is, is it useful? Is it worth learning? I've learned this is largely opinion-based, although at the cost of a question ban, I mean the question is not even good for the site. I thought I knew what the site was about, we're all trying to construct a knowledge base here, but now I'm not sure of what.

Comment: ...Bad OO code becomes rotten and unmaintainable, complex code needs to abstract away and handle that complexity, OO seemed a solution although also a problem. I want to believe that properly implementing a solution instead of blindly doing it is a good path to follow.

Comment: In its simplest form, object-orientation is simply about bundling code and data into a single responsibility, and communicating with other bundles of code and data via messages.  Get that right, and you're 90 percent there.  Unfortunately, I think the way you do this well is by gaining experience, and the way you get that experience is by writing a lot of code.  There are several architectural models that point the way, but none of them are prescriptive; they merely provide guidance and a possible path to learning how to do it better.

Comment: @RobertHarvey What do you mean by architectural models? Could you cite examples?

Comment: Spiral, Clean Architecture, Onion, Model-View-Controller, Model-View-ViewModel, to name just a few.  They all accomplish similar things. MVC and MVVM revolutionized my thinking about writing software, because they provide frameworks for a very simple idea: *separating UI from the rest of the system.*  I had learned this principle years before by accident, and it enabled me to get out of writing spaghetti code, but MVC and MVVM provide direct support for the idea.

Comment: I think a good solution goes through a good software architecture, but I also think there is a difference between "doing the right thing" (finding out how to solve a problem) and "doing the thing right" (architecture). I think I need to improve on both, not only the latter.

Comment: There are many ways to "do the thing right."  Inevitably, your approach will evolve towards the way that best suits your software's specific requirements.  Architectural models like Clean and Onion are merely guidance to help you do that.

Comment: I'm with @RobertHarvey here. When you say "I just want to learn how to properly design my classes", well... There is no single "the proper way". Ask 50 experienced developers how to "properly design" any moderately complex business process and you're likely to get at least 50 different answers, all informed by 50 unique sets of experience.

Comment: @EricKing You sound like learning from 1, 5, 10 sets or learning from none are the same thing. And like people don't come to agreements regarding software design. I agree it's a difficult task; domain modeling is remarkably difficult, and I particularly struggle a lot at that. Architecture is not the only thing that can go wrong in development. But if I can't learn something from the software industry experience, I'll stay designing ad hoc forever and suffering from the consequences of badly designed code. I don't have time to study forever but any amount of knowledge is better than none.

Comment: You're in the Software Development field.  If you're doing your job well, you will be in school the rest of your life.  But really this is no different than any other field nowadays; whether your an electrician, plumber or auto mechanic, you must constantly be retooling and re-educating yourself.  Auto mechanics don't deal with carburetors anymore; they deal with computer-controlled fuel-injectors.  Plumbers and electricians must stay up to date on changes in building codes.

Comment: But the education problem is especially acute in our field.  The way we develop software today is radically different than the way we used to develop it just five short years ago.  That's why there's no such thing as The One True Way.™  So we provide degrees and certifications in software development to educate newcomers to our field.  Unfortunately we seem to be graduating a generation of people who simply want to be told what to do.  You will distinguish yourself from this crown by figuring out how to solve problems, get stuff done and think for yourself.

Comment: I'm well aware I'll be studying forever. What I meant is that I cannot stay studying too long about something that doesn't result in benefit. C'mon folks, don't be so picky.

Comment: There is no shortcut.  If you want to to be a great programmer and not a pedestrian one, you have to skin your knees a few times.  The only way I know of to do that is to write a lot of code.  You can speed this process up a bit by getting ideas from others in the field, by studying their code and their architectures.  But nothing substitutes for grinding out a lot of code.  That's how you develop your sense of good technique and bad technique, what works and what doesn't.

Comment: It's like learning how to ride a bike.  Nobody can show you how to do that; you have to get on the bike, fall over a lot, and eventually develop your sense of balance.

Comment: The admonishments are unfit here.

Comment: There is not even a reasonable agreement what ***object-oriented*** means, let alone how a good design should look like or what process we should follow to achieve it. So no, not even close.

Comment: _"how  good design should look like"_ - we do have lists of code smells, anti-patterns, design principles, SOLID principles, don't we? And object-oriented metrics. Aren't they sufficient?

Comment: @Piovezan: No, those things are not sufficient.  They are useful for guidance, but *experience* is the greatest  teacher.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Since the question looks like it'll eventually be deleted, I may as well ask: what exactly was the reason you lectured me? I don't understand. Was it because I said I was a slow learner [here](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/402878/93338)? I noticed you didn't answer me back then. That's not laziness or wanting to be told what to do, that's a difficulty. Or was it because I asked the question in the first place? Or was it because I said I don't have time to study forever? I'd be really glad if you could clarify it.

Comment: Sounds like you're taking this personally.  It isn't personal.  It's just my way of asking you to try and think for yourself.  Like many others that are new to the software development field, there exists this assumption that software development is somehow a step-by-step process, like baking a cake.  It isn't; it never was.  I'm sorry if your education somehow failed you, but writing programs is not a [software] pattern-matching exercise.  Patterns and practices are merely guidance, not a blueprint.

Comment: Come to think of it, baking a cake is not really a step-by-step process either.  You can't cook anything for the first time and expect it to taste the same as the dish Wolfgang Puck or Gordon Ramsay cooks.  There are simply too many variables that are not described in the recipe.  I didn't become a reasonably good cook until I first learned how to use heat.  New developers often latch onto the Single Responsibility Principle as a mantra for writing programs, but until they gain experience, they won't understand the principle. Experience is what you always get right after you need it.

Comment: So it was me asking for a cookie-cutter solution. I see. Well I just asked for some formality because my experience lacks any formality and method. In my years of experience I did my share of coding but never had the opportunity to design a domain model, to apply a layered architecture, to separate concerns as in desktop MVC. I don't think they could be worse than ad hoc programming. This is why I think I'm in the right path, looking for some formality, that I had my reasons to ignore for so many years.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The terms OOA and OOD were created at the beginning of the 1990s, with the (debateable) mindset of having separate "phases" analysis, design and implemention in the development process, and the idea of "extending" object orientation from the "implementation phase" to the "former phases". Peter Coad and Edward Yourdon wrote two books about it with exactly those titles "Object Oriented Analysis" and "Object Oriented Design". You will find an introduction to [their ideas here](http://pages.cpsc.ucalgary.ca/~eberly/Courses/CPSC333/Lectures/OOA/components.html). These methods tried to distinguish themselves from older techniques like [structured analysis](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/system_analysis_and_design/system_analysis_and_design_structured.htm).

OOA and OOD describe *tools* for making analysis and design with OO means (like objects & classes, attributes & associations), but not the order in which they are applied. The way I understand these terms they are quite orthogonal to the specific software development process (like waterfall model, iterative model, spiral model).

At the time when the terms were becoming popular, there were some competing graphical notations for modeling classes and business processes. This lead finally to the UML standard. I am pretty sure today the terms "OOA/OOD" will be used synonymously to "doing analysis/design using UML" by most people.

Now, when does one make a certain analysis or design activity during a development (like scetching an UI, or drawing an activity diagram)? That depends on

- what the development process model dictates (at least in a waterfall model)
- what makes sense for the specific kind of software and/or the specific iteration (in some reasonable development model)

but it does **not** depend on if you are using OO and/or UML means for this.

Let me give some examples:

- when you are creating a new version of a software where the only task is to implement a new "coorporate look" at the UI, your first and foremost analysis activitiy will be to create the new UI, nothing else.
- when you design a software like a specific purpose library without any user interface, the question of when to apply the activity "user interface design" is pointless.
- when you have build a system over a certain time period in several iterations, and for the last iteration it will be necessary to change some behaviour in the order in which some files are processes, and you think an activity diagram is well suited to describe this change, then you will use this kind of diagram at a very late phase of your development. An UI design will probably not be necessary here.

So "Object Oriented Analysis and Design" is not a process model, but it is nethertheless reasonably defined (at least, to some degree - surely they are differences between different authors). And software development (object oriented or not) is not like a conveyor-belt process where you just

- shovel some requirements into,
- follow a step-by-step-list in a fixed oorder like "first draw an activity diagram, then scetch an UI, then make a class diagram, then write some code"

to finally get some business application as a result. It is activity where you need to use your brain and think what steps makes most sense next, for your current situation.

Comment: I'm afraid that despite our opinion, OOAD is not well defined, maybe not even useful. Wish I had asked a more constructive question. Regarding your answer, I don't know what non-OO analysis/design looks like, but I can't find anything to disagree about. Even about the conveyor-belt process, I guess I'm suffering from the hammer/nail syndrome -- "when all you know how to use is a hammer, everything looks like a nail." I'm afraid it won't attract many upvotes though.

Comment: @Piovezan: OOA and OOD are not "well defined" in a mathematical sense", but that does not mean those terms are not clearly defined from a practical point of view (at least, by certain authors, see some added history in my answer). If such methods are useful or not **for you** is your very personal opinion, and it does not mean they are not useful for the rest of the world.

Comment: Yea ... this is a classic "opinion based" question that seems designed to start a discussion.  Not here thanks.

Comment: What about now?

Comment: @Piovezan: I don't know what you are expecting - I don't feel motivated to rewrite my answer (though I guess it will still fit to what you asked now). And I doubt the persons who closed your question feel motivated to reopen your question even now (but I cannot speak for them).

Comment: @DocBrown I also think the answer fits the question as it stands. I just thought it is going to be removed, so I thought I'd give it a last try - but I understand.